# bash "find" command cannot search in ~/Documents folder on macOS

Tags: macos, bash

I am writing a bash script which shows all large files in your System.
I received an error message when i tried to find anything in ~/Library, ~/System, ~/.Trash and ~/Pictures but i also got one when i try to search in ~/Documents folder.
Even if i rum my script as root user.

The find command in my script:

```
find /Users/fabian -type d \( -path /Users/fabian/Library -o -path /Users/fabian/System -o -path /Users/fabian/.Trash -o -path /Users/fabian/Pictures \) -prune -o -size +10G -print
```

The output:

```
find: /Users/fabian/Documents: Operation not permitted
```

Is this happening because my Document folder automatically uploads everything to the ICloud?

Do you know why this is not possible Or even better how to fix it?

Best regards fabian

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo`?

Comment: ^Even if i run my Script as root user.^

Comment: [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/425572)?

Comment: First of all, thank you this really helped.